# Can a Jedi *reflect* blaster bolts with their hands?

Tags: star-wars

I know some Force-users can deflect blaster bolts with their hands, but can they also have the bolt reflected back at their attacker barehanded? Any examples?

Comment: Who can? If you mean Vader, then as per canon it wasn't "with their hands", it was with a glove made of Mandalorian Iron.

Comment: Yoda can absorb force lightning with his hands using the force.

Comment: @Jared - force lightning != blaster bolt.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it wasn't just the glove...use of the force also played a role there. Also, if I had to guess, force lightning probably has more energy than a blaster bolt.

Comment: @DVK-in-Florida - Or was it made of cortosis, which can also conduct energy?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a Jedi or Sith can reflect blaster bolts with their hand using [Force deflection](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_deflection)

Episode V, in Cloud City, Darth Vader also use [Force deflection](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_deflection) to deflect shot from Han Solo. 
There also another question about this.
[Why did Darth Vader choose to take shots from Han Solo?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11159/why-did-darth-vader-choose-to-take-shots-from-han-solo)

Comment: "Force deflection" seems to be no longer canon (it's listed as *Legends* in Wookieepedia), so this cannot be the answer. Same goes for the "Mandalorian crushgaunts" that some mentioned in the question you linked to. My own opinion is that Vader deflected the bolts 'cause he is a badass and the [Rule of Cool](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfCool) reigns supreme in Star Wars. As it should.

Comment: @AndresF. _The Empire Strikes Back_ isn’t canon any more?

Comment: @Paul D. Waite that's not what I said back in 2015, is it? I said the power called "Force Deflection" was not canon anymore (I haven't checked if this has been updated since). There are possible alternative explanations on how Vader could deflect the shots with his hand (the "rule of cool" being of course the default one).

Answer (score 3):

No. That is a special quality of the lightsaber that allows for bolts to be deflected.  Bolts can be absorbed by hand but in most games this is mitigated through strain or or drain on force abilities.  It is much easier to deflect.  The absorption is done to make a point, *you will not succeed in attacking me*, or to prevent errant deflections from harming bystanders.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

It seems quite likely that it is not a common power, but a sufficiently powerful Force wielder could deflect a blaster bolt with their bare hand. In *Star Wars Annual 1*, when the Rebel Eneb Ray mounts an ill-conceived assassination attempt on Darth Sidious, the Dark Lord of the Sith deflects his blaster bolt with his hand, with the reflected bolt flying off in all directions:

[image]

As for reflecting it *back* at an attacker, there doesn’t seem to be any particular reason that Sidious couldn’t deflect the bolt back in a direction of his choosing, if he can deflect it. That is, after all, what Jedi and Sith do with lightsabers. A hand is a different tool, but the principle seems the same: applying an opposing force to move the bolt in the direction of one’s choosing.

<sub>And, of course, as an indirect interpretation of “reflecting a blaster bolt with one’s hands,” one could simply use the Force to stop a blaster bolt, as Kylo Ren does, and then turn it back upon the one who fired it.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There is a rare ability among the Jedi called [Tutaminis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tutaminis). It allows the user to absorb or deflect an energy-based attack. I guess if they aimed right, they could "reflect" it back to the attacker, but I've never seen it. [Master Shaak Ti](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shaak_Ti) used this, although she possessed only an elementary knowledge of it. Master Yoda used it in his duel with Count Dooku, and Vader used it in Episode V, when Han Solo fired some blaster bolts at him. I'm not sure about lightsabers or blaster bolts, but you can redirect lightning, as Yoda does with Dooku in Episode II. So, Jedi can "deflect" blaster bolts, but I don't know about "reflecting."

Comment: If you can find any video sources or text quotes to support your answer, you'll attract more upvotes and improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes.

In the canonical novel *Ashoka*, the former-Jedi titular character is capable of doing so, but realizes that it would be too risky to do so while on the run.

> She couldn't use the Force for anything as showy as deflecting blaster bolts, but she could jump and she could run, and that would have to be enough.

Comment: Can you expand the quote to provide more context, because as-is, that can be interpreted as saying she can't do it at all.