# Why don't the Jedi use tutaminis instead of using their lightsabers?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-force

[*Tutaminis*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tutaminis) (force energy absorption) allows a Jedi to catch blaster bolts and even stop lightsabers with their body using the Force:

[image]

Why don't the Jedi just use *tutaminis* to defend themselves instead of worrying about lightsaber combat?

Comment: Tutaminis seems to be effective against energy based attacks like force lightning or force bolts. There is, however, no mention of it being able to defend against a lightsaber blade cutting off your limb, the entire senate chamber crashing down on you, or being fried by lava.

Comment: Ugh. I'm guessing this is a retcon to explain how Vader was able to block Solo's blaster fire.

Comment: It may be a retcon, but retcons are usually so much more elaborate than anything that could have been thought of before.

Comment: I dunno. Solo's blaster shots [during his encounter](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHH6YVHGh90) with Vader look more like they were deflected than an absorbed.

Comment: @Ian MacDonald I don't think it shows a deflection .  Just that it hits Vader's hand and that's it.

Comment: The blast doesn't deflect intact, but it clearly deflects (note the sparks and smoke).

Comment: I always thought that's just what a blaster bolt hitting an artificial hand would do.

Comment: @Liesmith So you think Vader's hand took damage? I never assumed that.

Comment: @fredsbend, I think Liesmith think his hand is made out of strong (likely expensive) materials that would take limited permanent damage from hand blaster fire. Or at least, that's what I always thought.

Comment: @PaulDraper I'm not saying that's not what Lucas had in mind, but even as a child I just assumed it was some Force trick, because he disarms solo via the Force after a few shots. Further, Luke's machine hand at the end of that film doesn't look too durable, but maybe that was different.

Comment: @LenieLenape It clearly shows deflection. At about the 9.5 second mark you see one of the shots deflect and hit the (left) side of the doorway and spark/smoke. The next time you see the same spot, around the 13 second mark, there is a visible scorch mark where the deflected blast hit.

Comment: @CreationEdge, hm. After watching it again, it seems the second shot was clearly deflected, but the first was not.

Comment: I've made a [question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84611/did-vader-deflect-absorb-or-block-solos-blaster) to address this comment discussion. Should we migrate existing comments there?

Comment: About Vader in ESB, I and my friends have always assumed that Vader's suit simply has armored gloves, with palms able to deflect blaster bolts, easy when using force to see the bolt coming. No exotic explanations with technobabble (forcebabble?) needed.

Comment: @hyde You've just hidden the technobabble (a big part of technobabble, of course) - what kind of armour would have to be on the gloves, when Solo's gun easily penetrates Stormtrooper body armour? Are you seriously suggesting that he has better armour on his flexible gloves than the stormtrooper has on a chestplate?

Comment: @CreationEdge Thanks, I wasn't positive and was hopeing someone would clarify.

Comment: The book's not canon anymore, but Plagueis could deflect blaster shots with his flesh-and-blood hand.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[*Tutaminis*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tutaminis) is a difficult skill to master. As Wookieepedia notes:

> it was a rare feat to be capable of dissipating concentrated energy such as what makes up a blasterbolt or lightsaber blade.

If *tutaminis* was easy to master, no Jedi or Sith would ever die by lightsaber blade or blaster bolt. Of all the thousands of Jedi in the galaxy, Wookieepedia only lists a few dozen practitioners *in all of galactic history* known to have used it.

On the other hand, a lightsaber is relatively easy to wield. Push a button to turn it on, and you can easily block a lightsaber blade or blaster bolt with a little use of the Force to predict where it would hit you. A lightsaber is small and easy to carry, too.

Comment: Plus, it likely uses more Force Energy to dissipate blaster bolt s with your hands than a simple deflection with a lightsaber

Comment: @SSumner You underestimate the badass factor, dear padawan. To actually stop a lightsaber strike with only your hand would surely shock, stun, and bewilder your opponent. Even terrify him.

Comment: @fredsbend only because it's a rare thing, it wouldn't work that way if it was commonplace.

Comment: @fredsbend Heh, unfortunately it doesn't seem to have that effect on a Sith... https://youtu.be/Y77BsaCoOMk?t=3m30s

Comment: @TylerH He looked shocked to me. Then he looked angry. So, not terrified, but maybe he heard rumor of this particular Jedi being able to do it (I've never seen the movie).

Comment: @fredsbend It's a trailer for Star Wars The Old Republic. The Youtube clip includes the entire video. That Sith previously encountered that Jedi when he killed her master in another trailer (["Return"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OzdCdRPESps)).

Comment: *Wookieepedia only lists a few dozen practitioners in all of galactic history known to have used it* -- but the page you linked says it was "practiced by *all* Jedi during the Old Republic"...

Comment: @Thomas I think he meant that only a few could block concentrated sources like lightsaber, blaster bolts, or force lightning.

Comment: @LenieLenape Ahhh, I see.

Answer (score 30):

They *do* use it. Tutaminis can take many forms. According to [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tutaminis),

> Tutaminis was an umbrella title used by the Jedi Order to classify Force abilities related to energy absorption. Designated as one in a family of Control abilities, tutaminis techniques were taught to Jedi Initiates within the Jedi academy throughout the history of the Order.

One such instance, in Episode II:

[image]

If only Yoda had thought to teach Luke that...

Actually, perhaps he did.

> Luke Skywalker, when Palpatine attempted to torture him with Force lightning, attempted to utilize this ability in a feeble attempt at defending himself.

Being able to do that with blaster bolts or lightsabers is very rare.

> Nejaa Halcyon's abilities in this power were such that he was able to catch lightsaber blades with his hand, *an extremely rare talent*

Even then, note that Nejaa could only absorb them with his hand, not, for example, with his torso or neck. While undoubtedly a useful skill, I doubt it's any easier to block a lightsaber with *your hand* than with a *lightsaber in your hand*.

---

Real world analogy:

Some people can catch arrows bare handed.

That doesn't mean they won't ever die due to arrows, or even that they would be very good in combat.

It takes a great deal of concentration and energy. In a combat situtation, they will likely do well to also have a real offensive/defensive weapon.

Comment: Much of this is a copy from the Wookieepedia article without citation, but +1 for the analogy.

Comment: @Null, thanks. Since the OP took exclusively from Wookieepedia, I thought it was clear I was doing the same.

Comment: @PaulDraper it wasn't clear to me. This is only one person's opinion, but I think it is better to be explicit about where your quotes are coming from. (But I leave it to you to decide whether to actually make that change.)

Comment: It occurs to me if you caught your opponent's lightsaber in your hand he is now exposed to your blow unless he can duplicate the feat.

Comment: @Joshua you might have "caught" it, but how good is your grip? I'm guessing it's slippier than an eel in butter. Admittedly, I have never personally held a flesh-searing beam of energy in my hand.

Answer (score 6):

In the novels, the the earliest published example of this ability that I recall is from novel ***I, Jedi***. In this novel Corran Horn, rebel X-Wing pilot and one of Luke's new Jedi trained in the academy on Yavin 4, has this unique ability. (I highly recommend that novel, it's one of my favorites.)

Corran has the ability to absorb and redirect energy, an ability that he inherited from his father and grandfather. This suggests that the rarity of the ability is due to genetics. Jedi come in many different shapes, sizes, skill and power levels, and predispositions to specific talents, and this one is difficult enough that even someone with the genetic tendencies struggle to master it.

In ***The Empire Strikes Back***, Darth Vader does indeed use this ability, but a blaster bolt contains a lot of energy, and that energy can't simply be absorbed forever. Vader absorbed the first bolt, then used that energy to deflect the second. A lightsaber blade contains orders of magnitude more energy.

Unfortunately, Corran also inherited the inability to use some common Force abilities like telekinesis. The only times he can physically move objects or increase his strength and speed is when he first absorbs energy. If this inability is commonly tied to absorption/deflection then it makes those individuals decidedly weaker in direct combat. It's an ability for sneaky types, not brawler types, and even then best only as a last resort.

I would also note that if the disabling of a lightsaber for psychological effect is desired, the best way would be wearing gloves or armor made of a cortosis weave, in the novels it's commonly showed as interrupting and disabling a lightsaber blade for quite some time.

Comment: Vader used his [gloves](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Glove_of_Darth_Vader), not the Force

Comment: This is Star Wars. There are many legends told by many people throughout the ages. I am merely relaying what is said in one of them.

Comment: I'm merely referring to your paragraph about ESB - see [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/84612/769)

Comment: Sure, sure. It's been a few years since my last read of ***I, Jedi*** but either it specifically mentioned the relevant Solo/Vader incident in ESB, or something I read online about Corran Horn and his abilities mentioned it. That scene from the movie may have inspired parts of the novel.

The point of my other comment was merely that because there were so many people writing for this fictional universe and even it's creator took liberties, left mysteries and overlooked inconsistencies, so there usually isn't just one right answer. I only present one possibility.