# Did Vader deflect, absorb or block Solo's blaster?

Tags: star-wars

This question has come up in the comments of [Why don't the Jedi use tutaminis instead of using their lightsabers?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84564/why-dont-the-jedi-use-tutaminis-instead-of-using-their-lightsabers)

Here's the relevant clip:
[Han Solo vs Darth Vader encounter on Cloud City](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHH6YVHGh90)

Some think Vader was using *tutaminis* or absorbing the bolts.

Some think Vader was deflecting the bolts.

Some think Vader was blocking the bolts by either strong armor or a Force shield.

In the video, it's evident that at *least* one blast is deflected, because you can see it hit the wall (by the door) that leaves a scorch mark. However, the other shots are unaccounted for visually.

Is there a different view (wide-screen VA standard), behind-the-scenes, extra footage, script indication, or official novelization description that provides insight to account for **each** bolt fired from Han Solo's blaster?

**Update**
I count 4 blaster shots **in another version** (link lost), based on visual and sound effects. The last one is countered with Vader's left hand, instead of his right like the others.

One is deflected around and scorches the wall next to the left side of the doorway, from Vader's viewpoint.

Another scorch mark is *very* briefly visible on the wall to Vader's right, just next to the rectangular wall ornamentation. However, this scorch mark disappears when we next see the wall (from the outside of the room). At the same time, Boba Fett is inexplicably standing behind Lord Vader.

I never noticed the other mark until now, rewatching the clip over and over to count the blaster bolts.

However, this editing snafu makes me wonder if additional footage exists (that may show Boba walking into the scene) that gives us a different viewing angle.

Comment: Note that Vader has metal arms, and armor. I doubt he could deflect them with weak fleshy arms

Comment: Quite related: [Why did Darth Vader choose to take shots from Han Solo?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/11159/769)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Speaking strictly G/Disney-Canon, Vader deflects the bolts. The whole concept of Tutatminis is a purely EU originated concept, and does not currently exist in any accepted Disney-Canon materials.

From the annotated screenplay:

> The mighty doors to the dining room slide open, and the group enters the dining room. At the far end of a huge banquet table sits Darth Vader.
>
> Faster than the wink of an eye, Han draws his blaster and pops off a few shots directly at Vader. **The Dark Lord quickly raises his hand, deflecting the bolts into one of the side walls, where they explode harmlessly.** Just as quickly, Han's weapon zips into Vader's hand.

While the screenplay does not specifically mention the number of shots or describe each shot individually, it does note that multiple shots were deflected harmlessly.

**The novelization, however, paints a slightly different picture.** The novel makes specific mention of Vader's "gauntlet-protected hand". While this does not necessarily mean that the Force was, or was not involved, the wording *does* cast some doubt on how much was armor, or The Force.

> “I’m sorry, too,” Han snapped. In that instant, he cleared his blaster from its holster, aimed it directly at the figure in black, and began to pump laser bolts Vader’s way.
>
> But the man who may have been the fastest draw in the galaxy was not fast enough to surprise Vader. Before those bolts zipped halfway across the table , **the Dark Lord had lifted a gauntlet-protected hand and effortlessly deflected them so they exploded against the wall in a harmless spray of flying white shards.**
>
> Astounded by what he had just seen, Han tried firing again. But before he could discharge another laser blast, something— something unseen yet incredibly strong —yanked the weapon from his hand and sent it flying into Vader’s grip.

Comment: I didn't care for the tutaminis explanation myself. Even with extended canon it would be a retcon. Anyway, the screenplay says all of the bolts deflected into a side wall. Yet on screen only one bolt is obviously deflected, and it was not into a *side* wall. I know scripts are not exact, but I think that's an interesting detail. (Why was it only important to show one deflection on screen). I wonder if special effects *were* done for the other shots, but just didn't make it into the view.

Comment: One way to look at it is that ANH showed how cunning, ruthless and quick Han was - by showing him killing Greedo before Greedo got the drop on him. This time, Vader is so quick with the Force, that he is able to pull Han's blaster out of his hand before Han can even get a second shot off.

Comment: I count 4 blaster shots. However, rewatching the clip provided "proof" of another deflection, so I'm updating the question.

Comment: First, nitpicking on ***Side*** wall is pointless. But the latter part is important, is this video a special edition edit or theatrical edit or what. Were the blasts added in one of the 8 million edits?

Comment: Han definitely shoot first here.

Comment: @cde That's a good Q. I haven't seen the original theatrical releases since me brother owned them on VHS in the 90s. I've only access to the modified versions or YT clips.

Comment: I've got the 2006 release, which is the un-fixed and un-restored OT. I'll try checking it when I get some free time in the next few days.

Comment: Of note, I've looked at a few lists of comparisons/changes between the original and special edition (like [this one](http://www.dvdactive.com/editorial/articles/star-wars-the-changes-part-two.html)). None mention any changes to the dining room scene.

Comment: The name *tutaminis* is purely Legends (thank God, because it's a terrible name) but the concept of absorbing Force energy (which is really*tutaminis*) is certainly canon -- Yoda absorbs Tyranus' Force Lightning.

Comment: @Null Fair point. Is it ever actually referred to as a skill in the novelization (even if it's not named)? There's a handful of things that have vague basis in the movies that the EU authors ran with. Like the supposed magical Rule of Two that doesn't really necessarily exist in G canon.

Comment: I haven't read the novelization, and as far as I know there is no canon name for it. Nonetheless, if there's a canon example of Yoda absorbing Force Lightning I think it's safe to say that a Jedi could absorb a blaster bolt. Also, the [Rule of Two](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rule_of_Two/Canon) (and [Darth Bane](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Bane/Canon)) are both fully canon. Again, it is Yoda who gives us the Rule of Two: "Always two, there are; no more, no less. A master and an apprentice."

Comment: @Null not going to get into it here (I'm in chat if you really wish to discuss it), but [here are my thoughts on that whole thing](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/38245/5184).

Comment: I have long assumed that the Force was not involved and that blaster deflection was a capability of Vader's _cyborg_ hands. "Gauntlet-protected" or no, Vader does not have any human hands. But now that Kylo Ren can _stop_ a blaster bolt with the Force maybe it's easier to assume that Vader could _deflect_ using the Force.

If it is the Force, it's still weird that Force-deflection isn't used elsewhere in the films. I don't remember it ever appearing in the prequels. I'm watching some of Clone Wars now and don't see it used there either.

Comment: @RussellSilva It happens near the end of season  7, with a character casually deflecting multiple blasts from a Mandalorian.