# What Force Power did Kylo Ren used to stop blaster shots?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-force

At the start of the movie, Poe (is that his name?) shot at Kylo Ren, who then stopped the shot and held it in midair.

What Force Power is it? Is it a uniquely different power we haven't seen before or did Kylo merely used a standard power creatively? Are there any constraints on its effectiveness that prevented the same being done against Chewbacca's attack on Kylo?

Comment: Wookieepedia has an article on [Force deflection](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_deflection) that has cases of blaster bolts being repelled.

Comment: Related: [Have Kylo Ren's Force abilities been shown before?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110994/have-kylo-rens-force-abilities-been-shown-before) and the accepted answer makes for better reading than mine :)

Answer (score 3):

#### It's a massively OP version of [Force Telekinesis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Telekinesis)

> Kylo Ren was skilled in telekinesis, able to suspend a blaster bolt in midair and leave it harmlessly hanging until he was ready to release it.

Kylo Ren seems to be very proficient at it:

> He could immobilize victims in a paralyzing grip, to the point where he could control their motor skills. His grip allowed him to squeeze a specific body part, allowing him to choke people and even cause them to glide across the floor, which he did to a subordinate, summoning him by the neck to his hand.

Rey however, is possibly more powerful than Kylo Ren, with zero training:

> Rey, despite having no formal training in the use of the Force, was able to override Ren's attempt to use telekinesis to summon a lightsaber that had once belonged to Luke Skywalker, summoning it to her own hand instead.

Which would make you wonder what she could do if she really tried...