# How did Satele Shan block this lightsaber thrust?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, star-wars-legends, lightsaber, star-wars-the-old-republic

In the SWTOR game, there is a scene where Satele Shan blocks (absorbs/ dissipates?) the beam from Darth Malgus' lightsaber.

Was she wearing cortosis armored glove?

Or is it her mastery of the Force that helped her?

[image]

Comment: Related (not a dupe, but has some more info on the topic) http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84564/why-dont-the-jedi-use-tutaminis-instead-of-using-their-lightsabers

Comment: Satele Shan OP! Guess she wasn't Grand Master for nothing. :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is a skill named [*tutaminis*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tutaminis) (sometimes called Force Absorption or something similar). Satele's mastery of the Force allowed her to dissipate the lightsaber's energy. It is the same skill Yoda used to absorb Force Lightning:

[image]