# Is it possible to protect oneself from a lightsaber with bare hands?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

[The Father](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Father_(Mortis)) held Anakin's lightsabers with his hands. Ok he's really powerful.

But the point is, as maybe using the same Force protection from Force lightnings, one could hold the light of a lightsaber or defend using their own arms, or even protect their own body from it.

We see Vader using his own hands to defend from blasters on Lando's planet.

At this episode on the *Clone Wars*, when the Father holds it you can see the same glow around his hands.

What are your thoughts? Is it possible and common?

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to use the Force to block a lightsaber blow?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking could you [edit] it to be a bit clearer?

Comment: Basically, yes. A possible duplicate: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/84564/51379

Comment: Yes. I pointed my current opinion and i'm asking yours.

Comment: If you're not going to use telekinesis to hold it off, you can use [Tutaminis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tutaminis). It can be seen in [this video](https://youtu.be/SAkcolVxDy0?t=3m33s) - the whole cinematic is impressive, but the relevant part starts around 3:33. (Disclaimer: this is Legends territory as far as I'm aware of).

Comment: This video is from Star Wars: The Old Republic game, which is, indeed, Legends. But as i pointed, we have canon moments where it can be seen

Comment: @Adamant - More than possible. Actual